# How can I make grub mount a drive with "rw"?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I have this in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
menuentry 'Arch (on /dev/sda5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-aabbcc-dd-ee-fff-eeee' {
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd0,gpt5'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  aabbcc-dd-43d1-fff-eeee
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aabbcc-dd-43d1-fff-eeee
  fi
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda5
  initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
```

Where should I add "rw" **exactly** to make it boot writable?

Comment: What do you mean by “make it boot writable”? Grub doesn't write to files, it doesn't even have code that could do that. Linux expects the root filesystem to be mounted read-only, it's up to a boot script to remount read-write. [What are you actually trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Gilles, nothing, my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grub doesn't mount a drive as writable, but Linux does. So you want it on the `linux` line. For example:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda5 rw
```

Comment: Except that this is a bad idea: that's not how Linux distributions are configured to work. The root filesystem is initially mounted read-only, then remounted read-write by an init script.

Comment: @Gilles OK, but would it cause any problems? My Arch `grub.cfg` has `rw` on two different installations (I can't swear I didn't change it myself but I have no idea why I would have done so).

Comment: fsck won't repair on the root filesystem. That's all from the top of my head, unless having the filesystem already mounted rw confuses some boot script.